# Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 sharing volume

Tags: docker-toolbox, volumes

I'm trying to setup a environment trough a docker container on my windows 7 computer. I have problems with mounting a folder to my container. When I run

```
docker run -it --volume /C/Users/Public/docker_share:/home --rm ubuntu bash
```

I'm getting no errors but I can't see my files from my windows host in docker:

```
cd /home
ls
```

is empty but on my windows computer I have a text file and a folder in C:/Users/Public/docker_share

I have found multiple threads related to this topic but no solution solved my problem.

(Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after searching in many forums, someone posted the solution that worked for me.

When defining your volume, write the "c" lowercase (/**c**/Users/Public/doc). This seems odd, but it worked in my case, so just give it a try in case you haven't found the solution yet.